# $onInit is using its own scope?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Html:

```
<map street="{{firstunit.street}}"/>
```

Component:

```
@Component('CustomerService', {
    templateUrl: '/CustomerService/_UnitCard/MapComponent/Map.html',
    selector: 'map',
    bindings: {
        street: '@',
    }
})
export class MapComponent {
    private x: string;


    public $onInit() {
        this.x = 'y';
    }

    public getValue() {
        console.log(this.x);
    }

}
```

I have a class that uses a $onInit to set a value. But I can't use that value in another function. When I call the function `getValue()` I log a 'undefined'. How can I set a value to the class property using a $onInit? (using angular 1.7 with typescript).

Comment: How do you use that class?

Comment: It's an component.

Comment: `@Component` and `selector` are not Angularjs syntax but Angular 2+

Comment: Using TypeScript you can achieve something very close to Angular. http://jsbin.com/jipacoxeki/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Try
public getValue() {
        console.log(this.x);
    }.bind(this)

Comment: That syntax is wrong.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma, now it makes sense, thanks. Do you register that component to the app as the example? Are you sure it enters $onInit have you put a console.log in there?

Comment: Yes the $onInit is called. But it seems onInit has it's own scope. So when I call this in onInit it doesn't use the global class property.

Comment: Try with fat arrow syntax: `public $onInit = () => { this.x = 'y'; }`

Comment: When I use the fat arrow and `console.log(this)` I only see the `street` binding.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use self-closing tags with components.

```
̶<̶m̶a̶p̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶e̶e̶t̶=̶"̶{̶{̶f̶i̶r̶s̶t̶u̶n̶i̶t̶.̶s̶t̶r̶e̶e̶t̶}̶}̶"̶ ̶/̶>̶
<map street="{{firstunit.street}}"></map>
```

See [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5#3558200)

From the Docs:

> ### Life-cycle hooks
>
> Directive controllers can provide the following methods that are called by AngularJS at points in the life-cycle of the directive:
>
> `$onInit()` - Called on each controller after all the controllers on an element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized (and before the pre & post linking functions for the directives on this element). This is a good place to put initialization code for your controller.
>
> — [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - Life-Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)

The `$onInit` function should be provided as a method of the component controller. It is invoked by the `$compile` service after it binds the component attributes to the controller.

With components, the controller is bound to the `$ctrl` property of the component scope (or to the property specified by the `controllerAs` option).

If the `getValue` function is logging `undefined`, it is likely that it is doing so because it is being invoked *before* the $compile service invokes the `$onInit` function.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)